# Rails fixtures dumping all data in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been in Factory land for the past few years and have decided to come back to fixtures but am running into a problem.

In my `test_helper.rb` I have

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end
```

Then in an individual test case I might be doing something like `users(:one)` however the data for `users(:two)` and the data for other tables that I am not calling on seems to be present in the test database.

So, is this the expected behavior? I have a hard to believing it is, seems strange from an isolated testing perspective.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you load all the fixtures at once from `fixtures :all` statement. A rule of thumb in tests is to load only the required data for a given test (not all). This also could slow down your test running time.

If you want to load only the selected fixtures you could do

```
fixtures :<fixture name>
```

Ex:

```
fixtures :users
```

[Read more about fixtures](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

One more thing, do you have a particular reason to comeback to fixtures. Factories are the way to go; they allow you do organize your test data cleanly.

[Read more about factories](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures).

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue of why both users are loaded instead of just the one I am calling upon.